# Is it possible to use GPUImageView/ GLSurfaceview in recycler view?

Tags: android, glsurfaceview, android-gpuimageview

I am working on photo editing app. I am using GPUImageView to apply effects.I want to display multiple thumbnail size images with different different effects in recycler view so that user gets the idea how image will look after applying that effect.

Comment: there is no such class in the android SDK

Comment: @pskink i guess u misunderstand the question. 
OP .you can do that, lets say you have 40 effects, when user select the image, loop 40 times and apply the image to the adapter. be aware of oom and loading huge bitmaps

Comment: just use normal `ImageView`s, what's wrong with them?

Comment: Hi my idea is the same. Did you found any solution? I am unable load filters in recyclerview; image view blank/black.

Comment: Did You found any solution for this problem? I am doing the same, Please help me if you have any idea. Thanks

Comment: no, I didn't got the solution

Comment: Have u found any solution to this. I am struck in the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

bit late to the party but its a bad idea. It will slow down or even freeze your app in some devices. I tried to do this to my app with about 23 filters ended up converting each filter preview to regular jpeg thumbnails and using them in ImageView (with glide, down samples the image saving memory) in a recycler view